# Centering image on full page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've combined some answers regarding centering an image, so it will work on a full HTML page.

```css
    .image-center {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
    
    .helper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .vert-center {
     min-height: 10em;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .horz-center {
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    html, body {
     height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="vert-center horz-center">
       <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="img/image.gif" class="image-center" />
     </div>
    </body>
```

this way, the image will be vertically centered because its container is on 100% height of the page. this is usually way the image itself isn't centered vertically.

**hope that helps some of you.**

Comment: This should be in the form of a Q&A, not in the form of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you avoid so many 'bad' css styling conventions and go for something like below, as stated in the thousands of other SO questions on this matter.

---

## option 1

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

## option 2

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow; 
    width:300px;
}
.child {
    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
       <div class="content">XXX</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## option 3

```css
#outer {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align:center;
    }
    #inner {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div id=outer>
    <img id=inner src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

## option 4

If you know the size of the image (and div), you could apply margins like:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
   
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
 
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #222;
  position: absolute;
   
  /*Centering Method 2*/
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

## option 5

centering text is also a doddle in css

```css
.container {
  height: 200px; /*Set line-height to this value*/
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
 
h1 {
  font: 40px/200px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>I'm centered!</h1>
  </div>
```

## option 6 (IMO the best)

using background image positioning

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  background: #eee url(http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/4) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

---

So, as you can see, there's literally LOADS of ways to achieve this with just a few lines of code.

Comment: yes, last option seems to be a better solution which i haven't found online, maybe a better way to search for it was "centering background image" instead of simply "centering an image using css" which didn't raise full solution to the issue. this is why i've posted here, to help others who search with the terms i've used. thanks.