# Cannot center info contact info above footer

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, zooming

I've tried everything I could think of to center the contact information above the footer but the closest I can get is this. This code makes the table begin at 50% of the page but I want the center of the table to be at 50% of the page. I can do so but I find it impossible to do so while maintaining equal scaling while zooming in and out (e.g. the copyright bar on the bottom). Thanks for your patience.

This is my relevant CSS code

```
#push{height:80px}

#footer{
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-top:0px solid #dadada; width:100%;
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color:#583625;}

#footer p{
position:absolute;
font-size:1em; color:#4d4d4d; 
line-height:1.5em; margin-bottom:0; 
margin-top:0.6em;
background-color:#6A412D;
width:100%;
}

.copyrightbar {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.copyrightbar2 {
margin: -100px 0px 0px 50%;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
position:absolute;
}
```

and this is my html code

```
<div class="copyrightbar2">
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <font color="white">Phone: <a href="tel:1800888888" style="text-decoration:none">18008888888</a><br>Fax:1-800-888-88888<br>
          USA:<a href="tel:8002556214" style="text-decoration:none">1-800-255-6214</a><br>
          Canada:<a href="tel:8002556214" style="text-decoration:none">1-800-255-6214</a> &nbsp</br>
          </font>
        </p>        
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>
          <font color="white"> 
            Company<br>Sydney Australia<br>
          </font>
            <a href="https://imgur.com" style="text-decoration:none"> <font color="white"> Emailaddress@email.com</a>
        </p>
     </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="copyrightbar" id="footer">
        <p align="center">
       <font color="white" font size="2">
             <i>All Rights Reserved. </i>
       </font>
    </p>
    <div class="push"></div>
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide a jsFiddle please? :)

Comment: Fiddling with jsfiddle. I've never used it before. It looks very convenient though

Comment: Okay i created one with your code. How do you want the result to look like? :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qSia4
first image is what I want and the second is what I have (notice I changed the characters).

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27795697/3436942) for centering

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle with your code. Pay attention to your HTML structure. You didn't close every tag.

**Always close every HTML tag you opened!**

To move a div at the bottom of the page, add `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;` to your css file. More information **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)**.

To center a div you can use `margin:auto;`. These links may will help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

I updated your code and pasted it into a fiddle. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask :)

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kirito/hehozus3/)**